# use-package does not execute `:config`

Tags: init-file, auto-complete-mode, use-package

When loading `auto-complete` via `auto-complete-config` with `use-package`, then `:config` is not executed and local keymap is not set. (See example below)

**Why that and how to solve this?**

*Example:* save following into a file `foo.el` and run with `emacs -Q -l foo.el`.

```
(message "DEBUG: my-shortconfig start")

;; init package and use-package
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'use-package)

;; auto-complete-config:
(use-package auto-complete-config
    :commands (global-auto-complete-mode auto-complete auto-complete-mode)
    :bind (("M-<tab>" . my--auto-complete)
           (:map ac-mode-map
                 ("M-<tab>" . auto-complete)))
    :init (progn
              (message "DEBUG: auto-complete-config init")
              (defun my--auto-complete ()
                  (interactive)
                  (message "DEBUG: my--auto-complete inside")
                  (unless (boundp 'auto-complete-mode)
                      (global-set-key (kbd "M-<tab>") nil)
                      (global-auto-complete-mode 1))
                  (auto-complete))
              (setq ac-auto-start nil
                    ac-quick-help-delay 0.5))
    :config (progn
                (message "DEBUG: auto-complete-config config")))

(message "DEBUG: my-shortconfig done")
```

The expected Messages, after pressing `M-tab` in `*scratch*` buffer, are:

```
DEBUG: my-shortconfig start
DEBUG: auto-complete-config init
DEBUG: my-shortconfig done
DEBUG: my--auto-complete inside
DEBUG: auto-complete-config config
```

But I only get:

```
DEBUG: my-shortconfig start
DEBUG: auto-complete-config init
DEBUG: my-shortconfig done
DEBUG: my--auto-complete inside
```

Also `M-tab` is not bound in `ac-mode-map`

*Note:* 
I found some questions to similar problems, but they do not help.
`auto-complete-config` provides `auto-complete-config` and `:config` stuff should be executed after `(require 'auto-complete-config)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you can expand the `use-package` macro to see what it's doing. Put point at the end and try `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` to see what use-package will do.

I suspect nothing here ever actually loads `auto-complete-config`. The commands you are specifying (and your own custom command) are from `auto-complete` and not from `auto-complete-config`. Basically you are telling use package to only load `auto-complete-config` when it is used, and nothing uses it.

You could put `(require 'auto-complete-config)` at the start of your `my--auto-complete` command. Then the first time you call it you'll trigger the `:config` block as expected.

Comment: thanks, I put `(require 'auto-complete-config)` into the function and use `use-package auto-complete`, then it works.

Comment: function `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` (instead of  `pp-macroexpand-expression`) needs less typing. :)

Comment: @jue Whoops, that's what I meant! Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is the working result of this question.
Now the `auto-complete` package loading is delayed until the user presses `M-tab` for the first time (of course you could select a different hot key). After the first `M-tab`-key press the global `M-tab`-hotkey setting is freed and normal auto-complete operation takes place.

```
(message "DEBUG: my-shortconfig start")

;; init package and use-package
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'use-package)

;; auto-complete-config:
(use-package auto-complete
    :commands (global-auto-complete-mode auto-complete auto-complete-mode)
    :bind ("M-<tab>" . my--auto-complete)
    :bind (:map ac-mode-map
                ("M-<tab>" . auto-complete))
    :init (progn
              (message "DEBUG: auto-complete-config init")
              (defun my--auto-complete ()
                  (interactive)
                  (message "DEBUG: my--auto-complete inside")
                  (unless (boundp 'auto-complete-mode)
                      (require 'auto-complete-config)
                      (global-set-key (kbd "M-<tab>") nil)
                      (global-auto-complete-mode 1))
                  (auto-complete))
              (setq ac-auto-start nil
                    ac-quick-help-delay 0.5))
    :config (progn
                (message "DEBUG: auto-complete-config config")))

(message "DEBUG: my-shortconfig done")
```

Note the extra `:bind` section, the changed package name and the `(require auto-complete-config)` line inside the function `my--auto-complete`.